Power Automate trigger condition not working correctly
I've created a sequential approval workflow to trigger when a Sharepoint item is created or modified.
I have set an additional trigger condition to only run the flow when the status of a sharepoint item is either 'new' or 'rejected.
When the approver 'rejects' the request the status correctly changes to 'rejected' but the flow triggers and runs again requesting another round of approval not allowing the user to modify and update the item.
The flow should trigger when an item is rejected but only when the user modifies something on the item again post the rejection, not automatically sends it for another round of approval.
The trigger condition I have input is below:
@or(equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Status/Value'],'New'),equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Status/Value'],'Rejected'))

The flow should trigger when an item is rejected but only when the user modifies something on the item again not automatically sends it for another round of approvals.
I expect the status to remain as 'rejected' until the user modifies something on the item then the flow should proceed and then automatically change the status to 'under review'. However, the way the flow is working right now is that when an item is 'rejected' it automatically changes the status to 'under review' even when the user hasn't modified anything on the item.
Flow part 1
Flow part 2
Flow part 3
Flow part 4
Flow part 5

what does your flow look like?

The flow looks like this

The flow looks like this: 1. When an item is created or modified -> 2. Stop sharing an item or a file -> 3. Update item (status = 'under review') -> 4.Grant access to an item or a folder (roles= ' can view') -> 5. Start and wait for an approval (sequential)-> 6. condition (yes branch : status = approved -> send email) (no branch: status = rejected -> grant access to an item or a folder)

Can you share a trigger body we can analyse?  Obviously obfuscate/mask any sensitive data.

Added pics thanks

I am not sure why this is not answered yet but experts can do it better than me. Let me tell how I handled this. I had created another status such us "Modified" to handle this. Eg. In your Trigger outputs (Outcome) field add a Value as "Modified" and instruct the users to flip it to modified once they make any changes after a rejection. That could re-trigger the approval workflow only after it is modified and the status is manually flipped.
@or(equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Status/Value'],'New'),equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Status/Value'],'Modified'))

So your flow could work like below:
New Item created by user -> Status Automatically flips to "New" -> Approval workflow triggered:

Approved -> Status flips to "Approved"
Rejected -> Status flips to "Rejected"

When Item approval is Rejected, user modifies the SharePoint item and manually flips the status to "Modified" -> Approval work flow re-triggered.
Hope this helps.
